# API formulations - are excipients required

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, drugs, pharmacology

I have the following API's

Itraconazole, Ivermectin, Fenofibrate, Pyrvinium Pamoate,  Sulfasalazine, Artesunate,  All-Trans Retinoic Acid, Doxycycline,  Atovaquone,  Extremestane, Syrosingopine and Mebendazole

Why is it that API's require excipients?

Are they necessary for the active pharmaceutical ingredients bioavailability?

Or are the excipients used more as stabilises, preservatives, flavourings, binders and fillers so that as a finished pharmaceutical drug, it can hold its integrity/ shelf-life / taste etc.?

Comment: How can you weigh out your dose of API? It would be very easy to overdose if you cannot do this accurately

Comment: Very true, lab scales with 1mg accuracy would have to be used. My main curiosity around the subject was more around the bioavailability issues lots of tablets have - I thought why couldn't API's be directly applied sublingual for improved bioavailability, but i guess the consumer wouldn't take the drugs if they tasted like raw API's - maybe nanoparticle encapsulation of raw API could be sublingual without the taste

Answer (score 1):

The ICH guidelines give some details about the presence of excipients, and the forms they may take (along with acceptable types/classes of excipients);

“The excipients chosen, their concentration, and the characteristics that can influence the drug product performance (e.g., stability, bioavailability) or manufacturability should be discussed relative to the respective function of each excipient. This should include all substances used in the manufacture of the drug product, whether they appear in the finished product or not (e.g., processing aids). Compatibility of excipients with other excipients, where relevant (for example, combination of preservatives in a dual preservative system), should be established. The ability of excipients (e.g., antioxidants, penetration enhancers, disintegrants, release controlling agents) to provide their intended functionality, and to perform throughout the intended drug product shelf life, should also be demonstrated. The information on excipient performance can be used, as appropriate, to justify the choice and quality attributes of the excipient, and to support the justification of the drug product specification (3.2.P.5.6).”

The major use of excipients is often just as bulk material in tablets. Many modern drugs are active at doses of 10-100 mg — these quantities are often so small that fillers are needed to make a tablet of acceptable size to be acceptable to the patient (compare to some older drugs where doses were often in the gram range).

Comment: Thanks NotEvans - it makes sense, I guess the main reason they use excipients to finalise the product mostly because it allows ease of administration for the consumer, by being in neat tasteless capsules as apposed to raw API powders which would require precise dosing, and in doing so, they then add further ingredients to prolong the shelf life once formed.